# Reshape one 4D-tensor into 2D whose dimension is None

Tags: tensorflow, reshape

I have one question about `tf.reshape`

E.g. one tensor `t1` whose shape is `[None, h, c, w]`. I want to reshape the tensor into 2D, just like:

```
shape = t1.get_shape().as_list()
t2 = tf.reshape(t1, [shape[0]*shape[1], shape[2]*shape[3]])
```

However, the first dimension of `t1` is None.

How could I process this case, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
shape = tf.shape(t1)
t2 = tf.reshape(t1, [-1, shape[2]*shape[3]])
```